# Java printing problem

Tags: java

I was having a text file as given below,

```
(DA1A11,Inflation accelerates, Thursday rate hike seen      )
(DA1A12, In India's grain bowl, farms face threat from MNREGS      )
(DA1A13, World off course on climate; renewables vital      )
(DA1A14, Sri Lanka, India resume ferry service after 30 years      )
(DA1A15, Hackers break into U.S. Senate computers      )
(DA1A16, India seeks OECD help to bring back illicit funds - fin min      )
(DA1A17, CBI looks into inflated oilfields costs - report      )
(DA1A18, Maruti loses millions on continued strike, fears of spillover mount      )
(DA1A19, Australia to warm up for India clash against New Zealand      )
```

i have to print data's as char by char from "(" to ")" then wait for 5 sec and start printing again, how can i do this.

Comment: Which part are you asking about? How to wait for 5 seconds - or the whole thing?

Comment: @lindon fox,  have to print datas between first bracess and wait fo 5 sec then start print the datas between next bracess. such that it has to repeat printing process again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        while(true){ // break condition here
            reader = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader( "/myFilePath/file.txt" ) );
            String line;
            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
                char[] chars = line.toCharArray(); // adding .replaceAll("\\(|\\)", "") for no ()
                for( char c : chars ) {
                    System.out.println(c);
                }
                Thread.currentThread().sleep( 5000 );
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle
    } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
        // handle
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle
        }
    }
```

Comment: After every ")" it has to pause for 5 sec.

Comment: now it is on every `)`. But, Note that it is better to read the Text from the file into a `String` and close the connection to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what you want. But I will try.

```
String txt = ...; // Your long text

System.out.println(txt.replaceAll("\\((.+?)\\)", "$1");
try { Thread.sleep(5000L); } catch (Exception e) {} // Sleep 5 seconds
System.out.println(txt.replaceAll("\\((.+?)\\)", "$1");
```

Comment: The sleep doesn't guarantees exactly 5 seconds, but it should be enough.

Comment: @Cosmin: Really? Can I read somewhere about it? Does this problem have a name?

Comment: @Martiijn, The thread may get interrupted (and an InterruptedException is thrown). Further more if you're not on a real-time system, it can't guarantee exactly 5000 ms. Strictly speaking, nothing can guarantee a sleep of 5000 ms as you have discrete cpu cycles.

Comment: But, interrupting a Thread... Isn't the only possible way to do this by working with other Threads in one Java app?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't strictly need 5 seconds, you can use Thread.sleep(), otherwise you may need a Scheduler, like Java Quartz, I didn't used it though.